# microsoft sync framework with mysql?

Tags: c#, mysql, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

Can I use **Microsoft sync framework** with **MySQL**?

Is there is good sync mechanism to sync multiple clients with one **MySQL** database server two sides sync?

Can you suggest any paid or free tool?

Comment: Do you need to compare and synchronize schema/data between two databases on different hosts?

Comment: I'm using C# with .net framework 4.

Comment: @Devart yes I want also to compare and synchronize schema/data between two databases on different hosts?

Comment: Have a look at Schema and Data Compare tools in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/). They allow doing this. There are also separate tools. Command-line mode is supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sync Framework has not out of the box support for MySQL, you will have to write your own sync provider for it. Likewise, Sync Fx don't do schema syncs.